# How to setup a Drush Alias?

Tags: drush

I want to setup Drush aliases for a Drupal site on WAMP. I tried, however I had no luck.

All my installations for Drupal sites are located in c:\wamp\www

Drush is located in c:\drush

I would not say I have multi site up!!

The URL I use in the browser is `caribbean.localhost`

I'm really not sure, or I have trouble setting up my Drush alias. So I wonder if anyone can advise me or offer direction help to me!

Comment: Please provide detailed problem, what it's show, what happen...

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to answer your question without some concrete specifics. But i went ahead and provided you some common troubleshooting tips when i was in your shoes a moons ago:

- Visit the latest [readme.txt](http://drupalcode.org/project/drush.git/blob/2aa15b5feb7e5cf9b53448c697e78361988b99ab:/README.txt): It's named that for a reason. I've never read a more helpful readme.txt in terms of contributed modules. Of the best. There's a section relating to site aliases as well. What you have to do for it to work etc.
- Review Documentation: First off, please review the [Drush documentation](http://docs.drush.org/) which provides great examples of how to create a site aliases.
- Copy an example: Also, the maintainers created some awesome examples for a `example.aliases.drushrc.php` file. In fact, theres a whole folder regarding this that you can copy and paste examples.

**Debugging Drush**

Additionally, here are some cheap tests to confirm that your site alias is working:

- Try running `drush status` a drush status will show which you which alias file is being read in.
- If that's not enough review the drushrc.php file. I would turn on verbose output to figure out how drush is failing.

Comment: it give me the this when do drush sa:

Comment: @Francis You'll want to perform a `drush status` to see what files drush has bootstrapped.